# Issue while installing twitter zipkin

Tags: scala, thrift, finagle, twitter-finagle, zipkin

I am trying to install `zipkin`, after following the steps given (https://github.com/twitter/zipkin/blob/master/doc/install.md), when I access `http://localhost:8080/` on the web browser, instead of the zipkin UI, it gives,

```
*Channel Exception* at remote address: `localhost/127.0.0.1:9411`


com.twitter.finagle.NoStacktrace(Unknown Source)
```

and gives out an error on the query terminal.

```
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery: A server service  threw an exception

[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Cannot read. Remote side has closed. Tried to read 33554433 bytes, but only got 110 bytes.
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:354)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:215)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.thrift.ThriftServerTracingFilter$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ThriftServerFramedCodec.scala:216)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.thrift.ThriftServerTracingFilter$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ThriftServerFramedCodec.scala:150)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.tracing.Trace$.unwind(Trace.scala:183)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.thrift.ThriftServerTracingFilter.apply(ThriftServerFramedCodec.scala:148)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.thrift.ThriftServerTracingFilter.apply(ThriftServerFramedCodec.scala:123)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.Filter$$anon$5.apply(Filter.scala:52)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.Filter$$anon$2.apply(Filter.scala:69)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.Service$$anon$1.apply(Service.scala:14)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.filter.MkJvmFilter$$anon$1.apply(JvmFilter.scala:29)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.Filter$$anon$5$$anon$1.apply(Filter.scala:53)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.tracing.TracingFilter$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TracingFilter.scala:18)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.tracing.TracingFilter$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TracingFilter.scala:16)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.tracing.Trace$.unwind(Trace.scala:183)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.tracing.TracingFilter.apply(TracingFilter.scala:16)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.Filter$$anon$5$$anon$1.apply(Filter.scala:53)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.filter.MonitorFilter$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MonitorFilter.scala:16)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.finagle.filter.MonitorFilter$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(MonitorFilter.scala:16)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Future$$anonfun$monitored$1.apply$mcV$sp(Future.scala:92)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Monitor.scala:38)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Monitor.scala:38)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Monitor.scala:38)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$$anonfun$using$1.apply(Monitor.scala:103)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$.restoring(Monitor.scala:110)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$.using(Monitor.scala:101)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$class.apply(Monitor.scala:37)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Monitor$$anon$1.apply(Monitor.scala:141)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:     at com.twitter.util.Future$.monitored(Future.scala:91)
[error] FAT [20140204-16:37:05.539] ZipkinQuery:

 (...more...)
```

Can please anyone help me how to resolve this ??

Comment: it says 'only got 110 bytes'. Proxy issue?

Comment: can you please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to not having an instance of the query server running.

I'm in the middle of a re-write that'll simplify all of this. Until then, you need to spin up a query server.

Comment: Our Query server seems to be running at port 9411. And as soon we try to access http://localhost:8080/ , we get the same error as above on the query bash window.

Comment: What storage backend are you using?

Comment: Looks like there's a bug when using a ThriftMux client and an old school thrift server. Here's a PR for the fix: https://github.com/twitter/zipkin/pull/339